# Running Doom on KaiOS

Tags: doom, kaios

What is the best way to play id Software Doom (1993) on a KaiOS device? Googling "doom kaios" didn't return any results. I wonder if it is available from the KaiOS store in one form or another. I wasn't able to search the store since I do not have a compatible device.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/pelya/doom-kaios/releases

You will need to provide your own DOOM2.WAD, then import it into the app (open KaiOS file manager, click Options -> Share -> Freedoom). You can copy DOOM2.WAD from your old Doom 2 CD, or buy Doom 2 on gog.com .

There's no netplay, because netplay is complicated for various reasons, but it might be added in the future.

And there's no music, because OPL3 emulation is very CPU intensive and slows the game to a halt.

Comment: It is worth calling out explicitly that you're the author of this port. Though, I'm sure people could figure it out by comparing the github username to the name you're (currently) using as your username.

Comment: (also you might want to update your readme. and kaistore link)

Comment: There's no KaiStore link, because they rejected my app submission again today. My readme is perfect, thank you.

Comment: Your readme has messed up markdown and your repo still has a kaistore link that points nowhere (redirects to the store front page after not finding anything)

Comment: I've removed the broken KaiStore link. Readme did not have any markdown in the first place. I've fixed it a bit, if this bothers you please submit a pull request.